# How to add Bootstrap v5 to your Ruby On Rails app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add Bootstrap v5 to a Ruby On Rails v6 project and there seems to be 2 ways to do it [on getbootstrap.com installation docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/)

1. Using yarn: `yarn add bootstrap`
2. Using RubyGem: `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.0.1'`

Is there a preferred method between these two? Is one better than the other on specific cases? I'd like to understand the difference, because all the examples I find use the first option.

Comment: read about whole process here - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-a-ruby-on-rails-application

Comment: thanks @LovekeshKumar I really like Digital Ocean guides so that's great. It does mention some of the pros of going with option 1.

Comment: It may also help you. [Rails 6, Bootstrap 5](https://www.bootrails.com/blog/rails-bootstrap-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

After some research this is what I've found that solves my question above.

Method 1 seems to be the preferred method to add Bootstrap v5 to a Ruby app using the Rails v6 web framework. I couldn't find a single guide/tutorial with method number 2 for the specified Bootstrap and Rails versions (5 and 6 respectively). I did find method number 2 used for previous versions of Rails.

These are the steps I took to add Bootstrap v5 to a project using Ruby on Rails v6

1. From the command line add Bootstrap and Popper.js by running this command `yarn add bootstrap popper.js`. There's no need to add jQuery on Bootstrap v5 and make sure you're in your project folder
2. Add `*= require bootstrap` to *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css*. Yes, there's a space between require and bootstrap. Now your file should look like this:

[image]

3. In config/webpack/environment.js add the following code:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Popper: ['popper.js','default']
}))
```

Remember to save and refresh your page, restart your app with `rails server` if needed.

If after following those steps, the JavaScript still doesn’t work (like dropdown menus or the navbar on mobile not expanding), check your browser console. If you see an error complaining about `can't find @popperjs/core` then it means `@popperjs/core` is a dependency of Bootstrap but it didn’t get installed. Install it manually with `yarn add @popperjs/core`. Save and refresh, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn is a frontend package manager that is shipped with Rails  If you want to do it the Rails way, just run yarn add bootstrap in your project directory and Yarn will handle downloading bootstrap for you. Then you can import bootstrap .css and .js files in your application manifests.

Also Here is the guide I wrote about adding bootstrap and fontawsome to rails 6 https://dev.to/shahershamroukh/add-bootstrap-and-fontawesome-to-your-ruby-on-rails-6-application-3fm7

Answer (score 0):

After a while looking for an answer to make Bootstrap work on my app, I realized I was missing the line: " *= require bootstrap "; by adding this and following the steps on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bn9arlhfaXc), finally I could do it!

Thanks!

```css
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 */
```